# Append the li in ul

Tags: jquery

I have problem appending the li.

```
$('#clickme a').click(function () {
   alert("zsdzsdvzsdv");
   $("#tabss").append("<li class='ui-widget-content' title='" + name + "'>" + name + "</li>");
});
```

and

```
 <div id="clickme"><a href="#" onclick="addli()">click me</a></div>  
  <div id="header">   <ul id="tabss">
  <li><a href="/user/view"><span class="tab">Profile</span></a></li>
  <li><a href="/user/edit"><span class="tab">Edit</span></a></li>  
   </ul> 
 </div>
```

please advice

Comment: Why do you have a addli() method call ? Moreover avoid using inline events...

Comment: There does not seem to be a problem, and you have an undefined function `addli()`.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/K3uAN/3/

Answer (score 0):

Try to append like this:

```
 $("#tabss").append("<li>" + name + "</li>"); });
```

[Check on Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Yz5c/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add li tags

```
  $('#clickme a').click(function () { 
        $("#tabss").append('<li><a href="/user/view"><span class="tab">' + name + '</span></a></li>'); 
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K3uAN/1/

Answer (score 0):

i think this will help you...

```
$('#clickme a').click(function () {
   var name = "name link";
   alert(name);
   $("#tabss").append("<li class='ui-widget-content' title='" + name + "'><a href='/user/"+name+"'>" + name + "</a></li>");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K3uAN/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(function(){
    $('#clickme a').click(function () {
        alert("zsdzsdvzsdv");
        $("#tabss").append("<li class='ui-widget-content' title='" + name + "'>" + name + "</li>");
    });
});
```

you must bind event after document is ready

Answer (score 0):

The code you had given seems to be adding the li correctly. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mlhuff12/8hJEf/7/)

But there is a javascript error, it expects to be using the function addli which is not there. Since there is a click event in the javascript, onclick for the $('#clickme a') in the html is not necessary. So I took the liberty of removing that.

```
<div id="clickme"><a href="#">click me</a></div>  
<div id="header">   
  <ul id="tabss">
    <li><a href="/user/view"><span class="tab">Profile</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="/user/edit"><span class="tab">Edit</span></a></li>  
  </ul> 
</div>

$('#clickme a').click(function () {
  $("#tabss").append("<li class='ui-widget-content'   title='" + name + "'>" + name + "   </li>");
});
```